# Multiple tap and multiple navigation activity

Tags: java, android

Help me solve my problem. I'm doing the transition between the activity using the startActivity method.

If I press n-times on the button that initiates startActivity, there will be n-transitions to activity. How to make the transition was only one?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the button unclickable when you press it the first time.

The code is:

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```